Converting string data in between brackets into python lists
I have a lot of data sets in this format:
{{1,{{1,6,0-0:14.0.1.255,4,*},{1,6,0-0:14.0.2.255,4,*},{2,70,0-1:96.3.10.255,[1..2],0}}},{2,{{1,6,0-0:14.0.1.255,4,*},{1,6,0-0:14.0.2.255,4,*},{2,70,0-1:96.3.10.255,[1..2],0}}},{3,{{1,6,0-0:14.0.1.255,4,*},{1,6,0-0:14.0.2.255,4,*},{2,70,0-1:96.3.10.255,[1..2],0}}},{4,{{1,6,0-0:14.0.1.255,4,*},{1,6,0-0:14.0.2.255,4,*},{2,70,0-1:96.3.10.255,[1..2],0}}}}

and I would like to turn it into python lists or really any other data type that would be more practical for later use, dict would work too.
I have thought about ast.literal_eval() but all the data would have to be in "". I have racked my head on this for a few hours and haven't found a good solution that is robust enough to take any kind of data to be in between these brackets and separated by commas.

In general, you need a proper parser for any such text format. This doesn't look like any standard format, so you are either going to have to go to the source to see if it provides a parser, or write one yourself (a task that is far too broad for a single Stack Overflow question).

It's not obvious what data structure you would want as a result from parsing this string.

what value does * have as a list item?

You didn't specify what each value should represent, so I use numbers for each item
      import json
  data = '{{1,{{1,6,0-0:14.0.1.255,4,*},{1,6,0-0:14.0.2.255,4,*},{2,70,0-1:96.3.10.255,[1..2],0}}},{2,{{1,6,0-0:14.0.1.255,4,*},{1,6,0-0:14.0.2.255,4,*},{2,70,0-1:96.3.10.255,[1..2],0}}},{3,{{1,6,0-0:14.0.1.255,4,*},{1,6,0-0:14.0.2.255,4,*},{2,70,0-1:96.3.10.255,[1..2],0}}},{4,{{1,6,0-0:14.0.1.255,4,*},{1,6,0-0:14.0.2.255,4,*},{2,70,0-1:96.3.10.255,[1..2],0}}}}'
  
  data_dict = {
      key: {i: {j: item for j, item in enumerate(v[1:-1].split(','))} 
            for i, v in enumerate(value[1:-1].replace('},{', '}|{').split('|'))}
      for key, value in [d[1:-1].replace(',{{', '|{{').split('|') 
                         for d in data[1:-1].replace('}},{', '}}|{').split('|')]}
  
  print(json.dumps(data_dict, indent=4))
  

output:
{
    "1": {
        "0": {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "6",
            "2": "0-0:14.0.1.255",
            "3": "4",
            "4": "*"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "6",
            "2": "0-0:14.0.2.255",
            "3": "4",
            "4": "*"
        },
        "2": {
            "0": "2",
            "1": "70",
            "2": "0-1:96.3.10.255",
            "3": "[1..2]",
            "4": "0"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "0": {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "6",
            "2": "0-0:14.0.1.255",
            "3": "4",
            "4": "*"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "6",
            "2": "0-0:14.0.2.255",
            "3": "4",
            "4": "*"
        },
        "2": {
            "0": "2",
            "1": "70",
            "2": "0-1:96.3.10.255",
            "3": "[1..2]",
            "4": "0"
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "0": {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "6",
            "2": "0-0:14.0.1.255",
            "3": "4",
            "4": "*"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "6",
            "2": "0-0:14.0.2.255",
            "3": "4",
            "4": "*"
        },
        "2": {
            "0": "2",
            "1": "70",
            "2": "0-1:96.3.10.255",
            "3": "[1..2]",
            "4": "0"
        }
    },
    "4": {
        "0": {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "6",
            "2": "0-0:14.0.1.255",
            "3": "4",
            "4": "*"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "1",
            "1": "6",
            "2": "0-0:14.0.2.255",
            "3": "4",
            "4": "*"
        },
        "2": {
            "0": "2",
            "1": "70",
            "2": "0-1:96.3.10.255",
            "3": "[1..2]",
            "4": "0"
        }
    }
}

